# Jasmines expect().toEqual() operation

Tags: javascript, jasmine

After learning about the differences between the [comparison operators ===  and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) in Javascript I was pretty surprised that Jasmines equality concept does not correspond to either one. For example all statements in the following test suite are true:

```
describe('Jasmine asserted equality of objects', function() {

    it('is different from ===- and ==-equality', function() {
        var x = {};
        var y = {};

        expect(x === y).toBeFalsy();
        expect(x == y).toBeFalsy();
        expect(x).toEqual(y);
    });

    it('seems to imply element-wise equality', function() {
        var x = {'name': 'value'};
        var y1 = {'name': 'values'};
        var y2 = {'names': 'value'};
        var y3 = {'name': 'value'};

        expect(x).not.toEqual(y1);
        expect(x).not.toEqual(y2);
        expect(x).toEqual(y3);
    });

    it('does not imply equality of the respective prototypes', function() {
        var x = {};
        var y = Object.create(x);
        var pr = Object.getPrototypeOf;

        expect(x).toEqual(y);
        expect(pr(pr(x))).not.toEqual(pr(pr(y)));
    });

});
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to find any official API documentation for Jasmine. The well known [introduction page](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) only provides examples, and most other sources I found either discuss the difference of === and == or Jasmines concept of [custom matchers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html).

However, my main question is the following: **How is Jasmines function `toEqual` specified?** In addition I'd be interested in the reasoning for introducing this new concept of equality: Why or in which cases is `expect(x).toEqual(y)` better suited than `x === y` (or `x == y`)?

Comment: `toEqual` is fuzzy equals (less strict than `==` for references. `toBe` is strict equals (same as `===`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DSL jasmine has this concept of equality because equality in javascript can be [confusing](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) and in tests [readabilty](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2012/02/13/writing-readable-unit-tests-clean-code-handbook-agile-software-craftsmanship.aspx) is important. It seems that when designing jasmine they decided to adopt the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) concept of equality.

To answer how is jasmines `toEqual` specified you can see in the [source](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/toEqual.js) on github.

```
getJasmineRequireObj().toEqual = function() {

  function toEqual(util, customEqualityTesters) {
    customEqualityTesters = customEqualityTesters || [];

    return {
      compare: function(actual, expected) {
        var result = {
          pass: false
        };

        result.pass = util.equals(actual, expected, customEqualityTesters);

        return result;
      }
    };
  }

  return toEqual;
};
```

As we can see above it using util.equals() which in turn comes from the [matchersUtil](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js) function which internally uses the `eq` function.

```
    getJasmineRequireObj().matchersUtil = function(j$) {
      // TODO: what to do about jasmine.pp not being inject? move to JSON.stringify? gut PrettyPrinter?

      return {
        equals: function(a, b, customTesters) {
          customTesters = customTesters || [];

          return eq(a, b, [], [], customTesters);
        },
    ...
      // Equality function lovingly adapted from isEqual in
      //   [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org)
      function eq(a, b, aStack, bStack, customTesters) {
        var result = true;
      ...
     }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for referencing the sources! However sources are naturally subject to change and with more than 100 lines of code the `eq` function is not particularly descriptive. Isn't there something like the [Javascript spec for `==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) for Jasmines `toEqual()` - or maybe for a related function like Underscores `isEqual()`?

Comment: Not that I know of, there are probably not enough resources in a relatively smaller open source project to produce comprehensive documentation that an international organisation like ECMA can produce, so the source can also be drawn on as the documentation.